# How did $4$-distance in General Relativity become displacement in Newtonian Gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, metric-tensor, distance, displacement

In general relativity the christoffel symbols 'pop' out of the metric $g^{\mu \nu} dx_\mu dx_\nu$. When $g^{\mu \nu} dx_\mu dx_\nu$ is integrated it is a measure of distance between the $2$ points. Using this as a starting point we have:

$$ \frac{8 \pi G}{c^4}T^{\mu \nu} = G^{\mu \nu}$$

where $T^{\mu \nu}$ is the stress energy tensor and $G^{\mu \nu}$ is the Einstien tensor. In the weak field limit one can derive Poisson's equation:

$$ \nabla^2 \phi = 4 \pi G \rho $$

However, when Newtonian gravity approximated and integrated from the Poisson equation, we get:

$$ U_g = - G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r}$$

where $r$ is the displacement. More precisely if I look at the action in general relativity:

$$ S_{GR} = \int (g^{\mu \nu} dx_\mu dx_\nu)^{1/2} $$

This is a measure of distance. However the action in Newtonian gravity is:

$$ S_{NG} = \int (\frac{1}{2}m_1 v^2  + G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r}) dt $$

where $r$ is displacement.

I feel I missed something subtle on how distance became displacement. Does anyone mind sharing a proof with this point in mind?

Comment: What is the difference between the distance between two points and the displacement between two points?

Comment: also why do you need distance as starting point to Einstein field equation? And did you consider that density in case of two point masses is given by $
\rho=m_1\delta(r-r_1)+m_2\delta(r-r_2)
$? Might be where your problem lies?

Comment: @probably_someone I would makea difference when you integrate something like $\vec F.d \vec r$

Comment: @Umaxo usually one does begin with distance though right?

Comment: @MoreAnonymous Can you explain what the difference is? I'm trying to understand precisely how you're defining these two terms.

Comment: @probably_someone Distance: $ \int |d \vec x| $ where $| \vec x|$ is the absolute value and displacement is $\int d \vec x$. So if I integrate $\int_a^b |d \vec x| +  \int_b^a |d \vec x|  = 2 \int_a^b |d \vec x|$ whereas for displacement $\int_a^b d \vec x +  \int_b^a d \vec x  = 0$

Comment: @MoreAnonymous Ok, so they're defined based on path integrals. Where are path integrals used anywhere in the series of steps in your question?

Comment: @probably_someone The action is given by: $S = \int (g_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu dx^nu)^{1/2}$ (the geodesic equation which is a "measure of distance"). One the other hand when I have $ \vec F_g . d  \vec r$ there is a notion of displacement. I find it perplexing I can start with a theory which essentially talks about distance ends with up one of displacement.

Comment: More precisely Newtonian gravity's action is given by: $S = \int L dt = \int (T-V)dt$ which contains an energy term  $V$ which has displacement rather than distance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The displacement is hidden in the metric.

Notation $(X^0,X^1,X^2,X^3)=(t,x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Newton's equations are given by $$m\ddot{x}^{\alpha}(t)=mf^{\alpha}(x(t)),$$ where $$f^\alpha(x(t))=-\left[\frac{G M}{r(t)^2}\right]_\alpha$$ i.e. $\alpha$ component of the field. Taking Newtonian gravity as a curvature in spacetime, the required equations of motion are

\begin{equation}
\ddot{X}^0=0
\\
\ddot{X}^\alpha-f^{\alpha}(X(t)) \dot{X}^0 \dot{X}^0=0.
\end{equation}

We know that the autoparallel (geodesic) equation in spacetime obtained by minimizing the action $$\int d\lambda \sqrt{g_{i j}(\gamma(\lambda))\dot{\gamma}^i(\lambda) \dot{\gamma}^j(\lambda)},$$ (where $\gamma$ is the curve parameterized by $\lambda$) is given by $\ddot{X}^a+\Gamma^{a}_{b c}\dot{X}^b \dot{X}^c=0.$

Comparing with the above equations of motion gives us Christoffel symbols as

$\Gamma^\alpha_{00}=-f^\alpha$ which is a function of displacement. All other Christoffel symbols are zeros.